# Flutter is not recognized even after adding the path in environment variable

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter is not being recognized in the terminal. I added the path in environment variable.

Comment: where is your flutter root installation path and how did you setup path variable?

Comment: It's in downloads.I copied the path till bin and added that in env variables. If I delete the folder after installing and adding the path, will that cause a problem?.I didn't uninstall but deleted.

Comment: you deleted installation folder? so how do you expect it to work? did you follow all the steps from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows?

Comment: Thank you.It's working now, after following the steps you provided.

Comment: sure, your welcome